# Data fetch from JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from external JSON and I was able to `console.log` it, so the fetch works, but I am having trouble to print the values.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "shoes": [
      {
        "types": [
          {
            "color": "pink",
           }]
       }]
}
```

I need to get access to the `color` (pink).

This is my fetch:

```
const shoesInformations = "json.url"

const [shoesData, setShoesData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getShoesInfo();
}, []);

const getShoesInfo = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(shoesInformations);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        const { data } = jsonData;
        setShoesData(jsonData);
        console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

And my attempt to print it:

```
<p>{shoesData.types.color}</p>
```

I do not need to map through the data just print the value one by one `{shoesData.types.color[1]}`

Comment: `{shoesData.types.color}` doesn't work because `shoesData` contains the whole fetch response, not the `shoes` array. In other words, `types` is `undefined` for you. In `setShoesData` use `data['shoes']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you assign the whole fetch response instead of only the `shoes` array within it to the `shoesData` state variable. Try this:

```
const [shoesData, setShoesData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getShoesInfo();
}, [getShoesInfo]);

const getShoesInfo = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(shoesInformations);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        
        setShoesData(jsonData.data.shoes);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

and then when you want to present it first add a check for empty array or use the [safe navigation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Either do (if you really want it hardcoded):

```
<p>{shoesData[0]?.types[0].color}</p>
<p>{shoesData[1]?.types[0].color}</p>
```

or more flexibly something like:

```
const getShoesRepresentation = () => {
    if (shoesData.length > 0) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return (
            <p>{shoesData[0].types[0].color}</p>
        );
    }
};
```

and then use `{getShoesRepresentation()}` in your rendering. This will handle the empty array case and you can extend it to handle iteration over all shoe objects that you need. I strongly suggest you use an iteration approach instead of hard-coding the data like that. You can safely use it by supplying `shoeIndexes` which contains only the indexes you want to present and then iterate over them and create a respective `<p>` for each.

Comment: So @zhulien I finally tried, thanks for you the patience. The first hard-coded option worked for me! I think the whole time I just missed the ? in my fetch object.

Answer (score 0):

`shoesData.types.color[1]` won't work, you only have 1 element, so your index must be `0`:

```
shoesData.types.color[0]
```

Comment: I have more than one element, but I dont want to map through the elements and print the colors of all, because I don't need them all - just 10 out of 25, so I want to "hardcode" it by giving them number in array. But it does not work I am getting error = cannot read property color of underfined